# codeigniter 2.1.4 support for http methods custom routings?

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, rest, codeigniter-2

I know that codeigniter supports custom routing to another class / method 
e.g.

```
$route['product/(:any)'] = "catalog/product_lookup";
```

However does it support routings based on the type of http request calling the url like in laravel ?

e.g. using get method reroute like in Laravel

```
Read PUT /users/X  
Route::post('users/{id}','UsersController@update');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official, production version does not. Not a single word on that in [docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html). But...

This feature is implemented in the [development branch](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/tree/develop). It was merged from [this pull request](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/pull/2712). Here's a part of the development version of documentation refering to that feature:

> **Using HTTP Verb in Routes**
>
> If you prefer you can use HTTP Verb (or method) to define your routing rules. This is particularly useful when building RESTful application. You can use standard HTTP Verb (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE) or custom HTTP Verb (e.g: PURGE). HTTP Verb rule is case insensitive. All you need to do is add array index using HTTP Verb rule. Example:
>
> ```
>     $route['products']['put'] = 'product/insert';
> ```
>
> In the above example, a PUT request to URI "products" would call the "product" controller class and "insert" method.
>
> ```
>     $route['products/(:num)']['DELETE'] = 'product/delete/$1';
> ```
>
> A DELETE request to URL with "products" as first segment and a number in the second will be remapped to the "product" class and "delete" method passing in the match as a variable to the method.
>
> ```
>     $route['products/([a-z]+)/(\d+)']['get'] = 'product/$1/$2';
> ```
>
> A GET request to a URI similar to products/shirts/123 would call the "product" controller class and "shirt" method with number as method parameter.
>
> Using HTTP Verb is optional, so if you want any HTTP Verb to be handled in one rule You could just write your routing rule without HTTP Verb. Example:
>
> ```
>     $route['product'] = 'product';
> ```
>
> This way, all incoming request using any HTTP method containing the word "product" in the first segment will be remapped to "product" class.

The quick solution is to update `system/core/Router.php` with the changes from that specific commit: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/commit/af709d6ebe6ca75913d7a9eedb4fdcd76be45c50.

Also, the pull request references [Pigeon library](https://github.com/jamierumbelow/pigeon) for handling advanced routing configurations.

Comment: Doesn't mention how to install without using composer though.

Comment: @user3148070 It does: "Alternatively, download and drag the `Pigeon.php` file into your `application/libraries` folder. Autoload the library and away you go."

Comment: Actually, the develop branch currently supports http_verb routing

Comment: @ahmad Yes it does. I'll rework my answer to be more accurate. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for you input, hopefully CI v3 will be out soon

Answer (score 0):

yes you can give custom routing in codeigniter but you have to put this routing in route.php
e.g here admin is my folder name and login is controller in admin folder

```
$route['admin'] = "admin/login";
```

if you we type url `http://sonedomain/CI/project/admin`

then it will directly redirect me to login controller of admin folder

Comment: Thanks for your input, but as stated your answer does not solve the problem of a HTTP REQUEST type calling reroute

Comment: check this i hope this will help you http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/86113/

Comment: Thanks but your link is discussing about HTTPand HTTPS. My question is relating more to the GET , POST , PUT , DELETE kind of http request